# How to get the date of a PubMed publication using BioPython

Tags: python-2.7, biopython, pubmed

I have the PubMed ID of an abstract, e.g. `10748870`. I would like to get the date on which the abstract was published, using BioPython.

For example, the publication date of the article with PubMed ID `10748870` would be `Dec 1999`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `esummary()` function. The following example shows how it works:

```
from Bio import Entrez

Entrez.email = "your email"

handle = Entrez.esummary(db="pubmed", id="10748870")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(record[0]["PubDate"])
```